# set default color button in first rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 3 button like this, I want set default color when component render first time. Any idea?

[image]

```
<Button onClick={setChartDay}>Day</Button>
<Button onClick={setChartWeekly}>Week</Button>
<Button onClick={setChartMonth}>Month</Button>
```

My css

```
  '& button:active': {
      color: styles.color.white,
      backgroundColor: styles.color.darkBlue,
    },
    '& button:focus': {
      color: styles.color.white,
      backgroundColor: styles.color.darkBlue,
    },
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: You try to change the color when the button clicked? or just add color to the button?

Comment: I want to set first button color when render like image, and change color when the button click

Comment: the color that you set in the css , will be render by default.

Comment: yeah, but when i clicked another button, the first button will be inactive and backgroundColor will be white

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a default state in `useState` for the first rendering. In your case, it would be `Day`.

```js
const BUTTONS = {
  Day: "Day",
  Week: "Week",
  Month: "Month"
}
const App = () => {
   const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = React.useState(BUTTONS.Day)
   
   const setChartDay = () => {
      setActiveButton(BUTTONS.Day)
      //TODO: Logic for day chart
   }
   const setChartWeekly = () => {
      setActiveButton(BUTTONS.Week)
      //TODO: Logic for week chart
   }
   const setChartMonth = () => {
      setActiveButton(BUTTONS.Month)
      //TODO: Logic for month chart
   }
   
   return <div>
    <button onClick={setChartDay} className={activeButton === BUTTONS.Day && "active"}>Day</button>
    <button onClick={setChartWeekly} className={activeButton === BUTTONS.Week && "active"}>Week</button>
    <button onClick={setChartMonth} className={activeButton === BUTTONS.Month && "active"}>Month</button>
   </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
button.active {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```